# Create dummy based on character vectors in r

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, character-encoding, dummy-variable

I want to create a dummy variable if all entries (in cols value_1_value_3) are equal to a given character (e.g. "C"), or are NAs.

Toy example:

```
df <- data.frame(state=rep("state"),
               candidate=c("a","b","c"),
               value_1= c("A","B","C"),
               value_2= c("A","B",NA),
               value_3= c("C",NA,NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Desiderata:

```
df <- data.frame(state=rep("state"),
             candidate=c("a","b","c"),
             value_1= c("A","B","C"),
             value_2= c("A","B",NA),
             value_3= c("C",NA,NA), 
             dummy=c(0,0,1),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I tried (but does not work):

```
df$dummy <- ifelse(df[-(1:2)] %in% c("C","NA"),1,0)
```

Comment: `rowSums(df[-(1:2)] == "C" | is.na(df[-(1:2)])) == NCOL(df) - 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```
rowSums(df[-(1:2)] != "C", na.rm=TRUE) == 0
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

How it works:

- Make a matrix of checks for non-"C" values
- Count non-"C" values by row, skipping NAs
- If the count is 0, TRUE; else, FALSE

Confusingly, `df[-(1:2)] == "C"` yields a matrix, while `df[-(1:2)] %in% "C"` does not. To handle the latter, wrap `as.matrix(df[-(1:2)])` first.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `apply` row-wise and check if `all` the entries in the selected columns is equal to `"C"`, ignoring the `NA` values.

```
cols <- grep("^value", names(df))
df$dummy <- as.integer(apply(df[cols] == "C", 1, all, na.rm = TRUE))

df
#  state candidate value_1 value_2 value_3 dummy
#1 state         a       A       A       C     0
#2 state         b       B       B    <NA>     0
#3 state         c       C    <NA>    <NA>     1
```

---

As far as your attempt is concerned, `%in%` will not work on entire dataframe, you need to use `sapply`/`lapply` to check for values in multiple columns. In fact you can avoid `ifelse` here

```
df$dummy <- as.integer(sapply(df[-c(1:2)], function(x) all(x %in% c(NA, "C"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate(dummy = pmap_int(select(., value_1, value_3),
        ~ +(!sum(c(...) != "C", na.rm = TRUE))))
#    state candidate value_1 value_2 value_3 dummy
#1 state         a       A       A       C     0  
#2 state         b       B       B    <NA>     0
#3 state         c       C    <NA>    <NA>     1
```